# r Calculation based on condition

Tags: r, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe like :

| Zone | year | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Afghanistan | 2013 | 8.6 |
| Afghanistan | 2018 | 11.1 |
| Afrique du Sud | 2013 | 2.2 |
| Afrique du Sud | 2018 | 3.3 |
| Albanie | 2013 | 0.1 |
| Albanie | 2018 | 0.1 |

and I would like to create a dataframe like:

| Zone | Evol |
| --- | --- |
| Afghanistan | -4 |
| Afrique du Sud | -50 |

etc.

Where Evol is equal to :
round( ( (Value in 2013) - (Value in 2018) ) / Value in 2018 ) * 100)

probaly using while or substring?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Please read the information at the top of the [tag:r] tag page and in particular show your input using dput.  Right now its ambiguous. We can't tell whether year is integer or double.  I have done it for you this time at the bottom of my answer.  Also note that your sample answer is not consistent with the formula shown.

Answer (score 2):

First you have to use `pivot_wider` on your dataframe to get a wide format, then you can `summarise` by `zone`

```r
library(tidyverse)

ex = data.frame(zone = c("Afg","Afg","Afr","Afr","Alb","Alb"),
                year = c(2013, 2018, 2013, 2018, 2013, 2018),
                value = c(8.6, 11.1, 2.2, 3.3, 0.1, 0.1))

ex %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = year, values_from = value) %>% 
  group_by(zone) %>% 
  summarise(evol = (`2013` - `2018`) / `2018` * 100)

#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   zone   evol
#> * <chr> <dbl>
#> 1 Afg   -22.5
#> 2 Afr   -33.3
#> 3 Alb     0
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Fantastic, worked perfectly. I an still studying the code to be able to masterise it. 
Thank you very much

Comment: Let me know if there are parts of the code you have questions about, and I will update my answer

Answer (score 0):

**1)** Sort group by Zone and perform the computation and ungroup.

```
library(dplyr)

DF %>% 
  group_by(Zone) %>% 
  summarize(Evol = round(100 * diff(-value) / last(value)), .groups = "drop")
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  Zone            Evol
  <chr>          <dbl>
1 Afghanistan      -23
2 Afrique du Sud   -33
3 Albanie            0
```

**2)** If the data can contain other rows then remove them and ensure that every group consists of 2013 and 2018 lines giving the same result.  This is the same as above except we have added the ## lines.  If year is double rather than integer then use 2013 and 2018 in place of 2013L and 2018L.

```
library(dplyr)

DF %>% 
  filter(year %in% c(2013L, 2018L)) %>% ##
  arrange(Zone, year) %>%  ##
  group_by(Zone) %>% 
  filter(identical(year, c(2013L, 2018L))) %>% ##
  summarize(Evol = round(100 * diff(-value) / last(value)), .groups = "drop")
```

**3)** If you wanted to use only base R then (1) can be done like this:

```
aggregate(list(Evol = DF$value), DF["Zone"], \(x) round(100 * diff(-x) / x[2]))
```

### Note

The input in reproducible form is assumed to be the following. Note that we assume that year is integer.

```
DF <- 
structure(list(Zone = c("Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afrique du Sud", 
"Afrique du Sud", "Albanie", "Albanie"), year = c(2013L, 2018L, 
2013L, 2018L, 2013L, 2018L), value = c(8.6, 11.1, 2.2, 3.3, 0.1, 
0.1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: I get 
# A tibble: 0 x 2
# ... with 2 variables: Zone <chr>, Evol <dbl>

but I am still working on it  :)

Thank you very much

Comment: Copy the input shown reproducibly in the Note at the end and paste it into your R session. then do the same for the code shown in the answer.